# Facing error while trying to add Firebase on Flutter project

Tags: firebase, gradle, flutter, build, admob

I am getting error whenever adding **implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'** and **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'** into app>build.gradle, along with **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'** into android>build.gradle.
If I do not use this three things, app is working fine. What am I missing?

**This is the error I am getting**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
[!] Your app isn't using AndroidX.
    To avoid potential build failures, you can quickly migrate your app by following the steps on.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\HASAN\Mobile_App_Projects\bangla_jokes\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Flutter doctor screenshot**
[image]

**After updating licenses flutter doctor**
[image]

**Also, Why is this things always red. app>build.gradle**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate to androidx. Check here:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration

to know how to migrate the application to androidX.

Alternatively, you can update flutter to the latest version and create a new project that will automatically use androidx. You can update by executing the following command:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Tried but didn't help :(

Comment: Did u upgrade flutter?

Comment: Execute flutter doctor and add the output in the question

Comment: Added it, it is showing "Flutter extension not installed" but I have installed it on my Android Studio Plugin

Comment: Accept the android license

Comment: Updated the question, can you please check?

Comment: @MD.HASANMUNSI are you able to build the project?